# Unable to resolve host "api.backendless.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, backendless

Just trying to run the tutorial and i am getting this error. I just can't understand what is wrong. I am using initApp inside my application class, maybe its the problem?

Any suggestions?

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override

public void onCreate() {

super.onCreate();    
String appVersion = "v1";

Backendless.initApp( this, getString(R.string.backId), getString(R.string.backSecretKey), appVersion );
    }
}
BackendlessUser user = new BackendlessUser();    
user.setEmail( "michael@backendless.com" );    
user.setPassword( "my_super_password" );

Backendless.UserService.register( user, new BackendlessCallback<BackendlessUser>()    
{

@Override

public void handleResponse( BackendlessUser backendlessUser )    
{

Log.i( "Registration", backendlessUser.getEmail() + " successfully registered" );    
}    
} );
```

Comment: Is your network connectivity ok? Can you ping api.backendless.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you forgot to give internet permission in manifest file. Pelase add below permissions in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```